# For which purposes, projects and teams, test cases and checklists are better compared to each other?

Tags: test-design, testcase, documentation

I was wondering which advantages and disadvantages test cases and checklists have compared to each other. For which teams and projects each option is better?

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience I have found that test cases are much more impactful for rigorous system testing. Ensuring that any flaws in the system are kept to a minimum with the use of edge cases also being tested.

I have used checklists, however, these tend to be a more 'happy path' type scenario. I wouldn't expect to be finding any extra bugs following a checklist that states explicitly the path to follow.

I've supplied previous business users with checklists to keep them on the right path and then they can highlight any mishaps to us in an organised manner.

For example, say we are testing a field which is a date input. 
The test case will look as follows;

- Verify the user is able to enter a date in the format xx/xx/xxxx

Checklist will look like;

- Enter a date.

They are, at a high level, the same thing. However, one focuses more so on technical aspect and one is the happy path. Personally, I would never use checklists to carry out my system testing, however, I would provide it to business users testing the system for easy feedback and to ensure that the business users can carry out the functions as expected.

Comment: What is the "happy path" in this context?